# Get value of ListViews and display on edit form

Tags: android

I am trying to get ListView values that are stored in an array and display on an edit form when a name is clicked, for instance, if James is click the method onItemClick should display the ListView values on the edit form. onso I can edit the value but I'm not sure how to do that. When an item on the list is clicked I want to be able to display the values on the edit form.

```
<!--edit form-->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/page_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/email_icon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_icon"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email address"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress">
    <requestFocus />

</EditText>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Mobile Phone"
    android:inputType="phone" />


    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
    contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    // Add some Contacts
    contacts.add(new Contact("Jame ham","james@bloggs.com", "02125547"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Ken ben","ken@doe.com", "032547358""));


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);


    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Clicked " + contact,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    String Name= contact .getName();
                    String Email= contact .getEmail();
                    String Number= contact .getNumber();

                    Intent editActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditActivity.class);
                    editActivity.putExtra("Name", Name);
                    editActivity.putExtra("Email", Email);
                    editActivity.putExtra("Number", Number);
                    startActivity(editActivity );

                }
```

Then on EditActivity capture it and setText it to your EditText.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        String Email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        String Number = intent.getStringExtra("Number");
```

Or you can do it by Custom dialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOU_LAYOUT_HERE);
            EditText ETname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.etname);
            EditText ETemail = dialog.findViewById(R.id.etemail);
            EditText ETnumber = dialog.findViewById(R.id.etnumber);
            ETname.setText(Name);
            ETemail.setText(Email);
            ETnumber.setText(Number);
            //Add a button for your desire operation
```